# Django Join - I need all fields of parents and child table

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need two fields on the Result: headline,publications,title
I need to return on the all fields. But it returns only on headline, publications i have joined the Parent and child table. But i cant get the Child table Fields. I need a Two table Fields.

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'headline' into field. Choices are: id, manufactures, title

```
class Car(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('title',)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

class Manufactures(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Car)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)

     Car.objects.filter(manufactures__headline__startswith="Title").values('title')
```

Comment: Headline,publications,title i need to return on the all fields.
    But it returns only on headline,publications




    i have joined the Parent and child table. But i cant get the Child table Fields. I need a Two table Fields. 


    
    django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'headline' into field. Choices are: id, manufactures, title

Comment: Please try to state more coherently what you need. Feel free to read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the model, `Car` has no field `manufacturers`. `Manufactures` however has an m2m relationship with cars. Not sure why a single car should have many manufacturers but oh well. What you should do is add a `related_name=manufactures` argument in the publications field. In this way, you can have a reverse relationship from car to manufacturers and your filter will then work. But seriously you should consider your logic(ideally, Car should have a foreign key to the manufacturer) and also use singular nouns to name your models (Manufacturer instead of Manufacturers)